# JavaScript: unexpected token error

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a codecademy.com lesson where I'm supposed to check if a number is a multiple of 3 or 5 (but not a multiple of 3 and 5), returning true or false depending on result of the test. The method should also return false if doesn't satisfy either of the conditions.

When I run the code it's telling me there's a syntax error: unexpected token. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
var FizzBuzzPlus = {

    this.isFizzBuzzie = function(number){
        if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 === 0){
            return false;           
        }else if (number % 3 === 0 || number % 5 ===0){
            return true; 
        }else{
        return false; 
        }                           
    }; 
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var FizzBuzzPlus = {

    isFizzBuzzie: function(number){
        if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 === 0){
            return false;           
        }else if (number % 3 === 0 || number % 5 ===0){
            return true; 
        }else{
        return false; 
        }                           
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat off-topic, but it would be better to evaluate the modulo for both 3 and 5 only once:

```
var FizzBuzzPlus = {

    isFizzBuzzie : function(number){
        var d3 = number % 3 === 0;
        var d5 = number % 5 === 0;
        if (d3 && d5){
            return false;           
        }else if (d3 || d5){
            return true; 
        }else{
        return false; 
        }                           
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
    console.log(i + ": " + FizzBuzzPlus.isFizzBuzzie(i));
}
```